# Where can I find the active time of a MOA on the VFR chart?

Tags: usa, aeronautical-charts, visual-flight-rules

I am trying to find out the time when the HILLTOP MOA is active and its elevation. Where is this information located in a VFR chart?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's in a table on the border of the sectional.  Looking at the Chicago sectional, this is along the top....

[image]

Comment: Just be advised, published "normal" hours are not the same as active.  They generally aren't hot continuously.